# Is there a way to have the Trivia Quiz to appear on the layer as the game?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am making a game. Clicking on the "ülesanne" book should give you the Trivia questions (I am using the dhtml goodies script for that right now) but can you display the questions on the same page. Displaying it as a pop-up isn't a good option for me.
Here's the link

http://www.tlu.ee/~kristo93/Eritamine%20-%20puhas/p6hi.html

Comment: how about toggling an iframe from hidden to visible?

Comment: Can't get it to work. The iframe doesen't want to work with the Kinetic stage. Or atleast I can't get it to work.

Comment: well, it doesn't have to work with the Kinetic.Stage just overlap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WrXMy/2/) is an example using an iframe to display your quiz, which overlaps the stage and gets visible as soon you click anywhere on the stage by changing its css `visibility`-property from `hidden` to `visible`.

Comment: Is it possible to move a group which consist of iframe and kineticRect?